# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' with Form Save

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a fairly simple form, but I'm receiving a TypeError with the ModelChoiceField, and I'm unable to understand why. The form returns the model id number, and with that number I should be able to lookup the particular model and use it for whatever purpose. It's not working out that way though.Here is my form code:

```
class TestimonialForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea)
    ratings = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5')
          )
    rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ratings, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
    reward = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Reward.objects.all())
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(TestimonialForm, self).clean()
        usr = cleaned_data.get('username')
        res = cleaned_data.get('reward')
    if Reward_Review.objects.filter(id=res.id).filter(affiliate__username=usr):
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have already submitted a testimonial. You can only submit one per gift card.")
    if not Redeem.objects.filter(reward__id=res.id).filter(affiliate__username=usr):
        raise forms.ValidationError("You haven't received this gift card yet, so you cannot write a review for it.")
    def clean_username(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['username']
    try: 
        Affiliate.objects.get(user__username=data)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist, e:
        msg = 'The username provided by the form submission does not match anyone in our database.'
        logger.exception(e)
        logger.debug(msg, exc_info=True)
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid username. Please try again later.")
    return data
    def save(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    user = request.user
    re = Reward.objects.get(id=data['reward'])
    points = Points.objects.create(affiliate=user, points=float(10), from_offer=False, from_task=True)
    rate = Reward_Rating.objects.create(affiliate=user, reward=re, rating_value=data['rating'])
    testimonial = Reward_Review.objects.create(affiliate=user, reward=re, reward_rating=rate, review_title=data['title'], review_content=data['content'])
    return testimonial
```

Full Trace:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Traceback:

File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  29.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  25.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
File "/app/myapp/views.py" in dispatch
  756.         return super(TestimonialFormView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.8.0.7/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py" in wrapper
  809.             return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  87.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py" in post
  171.             return self.form_valid(form)
File "/app/myapp/views.py" in form_valid
  743.  form.save(self.request)
File "/app/myapp/forms.py" in save
  215.  re = Reward.objects.get(id=data['reward'])

Exception Type: TypeError at /testimonials/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: What is the *full* traceback of the exception? If using Django in DEBUG mode, the error page in the browser has a *show traceback as text* option; click that and copy the traceback from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form.clean()` *must* return the cleaned data.

Answer (score 2):

[Somewhere](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6.1/django/forms/forms.py#L300) in the django-1.6 `Form` source code there is a line:

```
self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
```

This means that you should return a dictionary from your `clean` method.

Something like this:

```
def clean(self, ...):
    // whatever
    return cleaned_data
```

Note: returning a dictionary from the `clean` method won't be required in the future versions of django:

> Changed in Django Development version: In previous versions of Django,
>   form.clean() was required to return a dictionary of cleaned_data. This
>   method may still return a dictionary of data to be used, but it’s no
>   longer required.

Answer (score 0):

Probaby the problem is here

```
 re = Reward.objects.get(id=data['reward'])
```

When using a `ModelChoiceField` your `cleaned_data` dictionary will *already* contain the corresponding object (and not its `id`) -- so just do

```
re = data['reward']
```

Comment: He he probably a full stacktrace would tell us exactly where is the problem :)